# How to update and save an app.config application setting programatically

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am currently working on a WPF/.Net project, 
In this project the user has the choice to change the the skinning of the app entirely, 
I am trying to write those settings after submission using configurations management, 
but I don't seem to be able to add the new values to the app.config file, here is my method underneath

```
Public Sub SetApplicationSetting(pstrAppSettingName As String, pstrAppSettingValue As String)
    Dim lobjconfig As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

    lobjconfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add(pstrAppSettingName, pstrAppSettingValue)
    lobjconfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full)
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
End Sub
```

any ideas?

Now the word on the street is that I cant Add to what is already there, So I thougth maybe I should remove it first before updating, 
but still nothing,  here is the new code

```
 Dim lobjconfig As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

            lobjconfig.AppSettings.Settings.Remove(pstrAppSettingName)
            lobjconfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add(pstrAppSettingName, pstrAppSettingValue)


               lobjconfig.AppSettings.Settings.CurrentConfiguration.Save()
            lobjconfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, True)

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

Comment: Could you share what happens when you try?

Comment: It runs through each and everyline fine, I also check the pstrAppSettingValue and its there, but somehow it doesnt get added to the app.config, (I also tweaked it slightly and added a True at the end of teh Save line to force it to save all) but still nothing

Comment: Huh? You just said that pstrAppSettingValue "is there", and then "doesn't get added"... which is it?

Comment: pstrappsettingvalue exist when im debugging but , it doesnt get written to the app.config , so the next time I run the application im back to the old skin again.

Comment: I'm guessing you are on Vista or Win7, or Server 2008+, right?

Comment: Windows 7 .... Why? is it different on thoes OSs?

Comment: You shouldn't store store your settings there, that's not what app.config is for. It is supposed to hold readonly application settings, and users without admin privileges won't be able to do this. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163812.aspx#S2).

Comment: ...and check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) to see how it should be done (if you don't want to do your own XML serialization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to change the configuration for all users (`ConfigurationUserLevel.None`) and that you might not have the right to do so. I'd expect an exception when that fails, and you didn't say one was thrown, so I might be on the wrong track.

To find the culprit, you might try `ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal` or `ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming` and see if that works better.

Alternatively, but I doubt it makes a difference, you can make getting the configuration from a certain location specifically by using the following line:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                          Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: This answer looks good, but now Im slightly confused how to type the path of the file, if the file is in the bin folder within the projec, can you help with that ? - Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: @AshShafiee: Wait, are you trying to update the config file that's not the config file used while running? When you run, the location of the app.config is different from the one in your project location. During running with F5, your application is copied to the build directory and the config file (yourname.exe.config) also. Changes can be found there, or in the system location.

Comment: To make that more clear: changing the config file through code while running with F5 (debug) or Ctrl-F5 will _not_ change the app.config in your Visual Studio project.

Comment: Yes you are right , I found it , The problem is fixed , Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Run the app in some location by double clicking it directly or Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio, the changes on settings would be persisted to the app config file (yourapp.exe.config) under the build debug folder. Through testing, running an app in VS through F5 (debug) and Ctrl+F5 (run without debug) is different in terms of the changes on app config file.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, AppplicationSettings are the preferred way for this if you don't have a 'skin' file. They allow for per-user and application-wide settings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx

UPDATE: I think you might find this link useful for creating settings
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171565.aspx

Also you can use the designer to quickly change from user-specific to application-wide settings too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx

Also there are many links here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=applicationsettings+c%23

Comment: I am aware that I am using application setting lol , so you are just point out a fact here,

Comment: Yeah. sorry. At first I thought you were trying to hack the app's app.config file, which as the other answer indicates your user may not have the rights for. Perhaps you're better off saving skin items as per user where you'll have the rights to save them.

Comment: I dont have much room to make further changes, IM sort of stuck with what is already here , trying to make it work

Comment: With ApplicationSettings, it's really simple to change from application wide to per user. FYI

Comment: could you explain further in an answer form please, the problem is still here,